# got "error: undeclared here (not in a function)" with void * variable array

Tags: c

Code:

```
struct bunchofdata
{
    int i;
    void *dllist[i];
    int spltq[i];
    pthread_t tlist[i];
};
```

Errormsg:

```
error: ‘i’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  void *dllist[i];
               ^
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: `i` is uknown so it will not work. It would be best to allocate this memory knowing i value.

Comment: Catch-22. The length of the arrays cannot be known until `i` is known, which can't be known until the struct is created.

Comment: Just look at it and think like a compiler.  What offsets are you going to apply for the start of spltq and tlist?

Comment: @CDnX compiler doesn't allocate memory until you create an object of the structure and array expects its size to be defined as "i" is undefined now, so it's causing compilation error.

Comment: @CDnX and this is not the way to initialize the arrays. use something like int arr[30] or dynamically allocate memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [pikkewyn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35687339/3528438), another way to implement this is to use [Flexible Array Member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

This makes it easier to manage than allocating members separately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int pthread_t;
struct data
{
    void *dl;
    int spltq;
    pthread_t thread;
};
struct bunchofdata
{
    int i;
    struct data data_list[];
};
struct bunchofdata * data_factory(int size)
{
    struct bunchofdata * ret = malloc(sizeof(struct bunchofdata)
                                      +size*sizeof(struct data));
    /* fill in the members here*/
    ret->i=size;
    return ret;
}
int main(void) {
    struct bunchofdata *data10=data_factory(10);
    data10->data_list[9].spltq=0;
    printf("data10->data_list[9].spltq=%d",data10->data_list[9].spltq);
    free(data10)
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like this, although since each field of your structure is array it might be nicer to have array of such structs:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct bunchofdata
{
    int i;
    void** dllist;
    int* spltq;
    pthread_t* tlist;
};

struct anotherbunchofdata
{
    int i;
    void* dll;
    int spltq;
    pthread_t tlist;
};

void init_bunchofdata( int size, struct bunchofdata* bd )
{
    bd->i = size;
    bd->dllist = malloc( size * sizeof( void* ) );
    bd->spltq = malloc( size * sizeof( int ) );
    bd->tlist = malloc( size * sizeof( pthread_t ) );
}

void free_bunchofdata( struct bunchofdata* bd )
{
    free( bd->dllist );
    free( bd->spltq );
    free( bd->tlist );
}



int main()
{
    struct bunchofdata bd;
    init_bunchofdata( 5, &bd );
    free_bunchofdata( &bd );

    return 0;
}
```